# asp.net mvc ajax.beginform onsuccess event

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Is it possible to do something like this using asp.net mvc 3

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("SomeAction","MyController",new AjaxOptions     {OnSuccess="function(content){ alert(content); }"}))
{
@Html.Partial("Recorder")
<input type="submit" />
}
```

I am using Jquery for ajax operations  and not MSAjax.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I use it and it is useful specially when you want to change an area content. Add UpdateTargetId and httpMethod as well: (new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "ShowBids" , OnSuccess="..." } )

Comment: If you're using jQuery for AJAX, why are you using MVC's AjaxHelpers?

Comment: thanks Amir, it doesnt work with mvc3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a normal Html.BeginForm, assign a id to the form, and use the jquery ajax to handle submission:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formData" }))
```

The submission function:

```
    // Function to submit form data
    function submitForm() {

        var frm = $('#formData');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Create',
            type: 'POST',
            data: frm.serialize(),
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            onsuccess: function (){},
            success: function (result) {  },
            error: function () {  }
        });
    }
```

Hope this what you mean/need :)

Comment: Thanks ophelia, isnt it reinventing the wheel

Comment: For me, its just 2 different methods and i prefer to use this :)

Comment: but you serialize everyform urself and then handle error and success urself. i understand you have more power now. but still i feel should i do it.